# Azure AD Connect password write-back failing (no errors)

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

I'm testing Azure AD Connect on a small "test" domain before I proceed with a full sync of our domain.

Unfortunately, I'm having some problems. Before I get to the problems, here's my setup:

- The name of the domain is NOT the same as the Azure domain, but an added UPN suffix IS.
- I've set-up AD Connect to sync only a single OU (for testing)
- The OU contains a single User with a manually specified email.
- The same user was created **manually** in Azure prior to starting the sync process. The Azure user was given an email licence, and an email address.
- Azure AD connect was set up with pretty basic settings. Password write-back was enabled as part of those settings. The system is set up to only sync that single OU specified earlier.

It appears that changing the test user's password in my local AD (and waiting for a sync) does update the password in Azure. However, the operation appears to be one-way, despite password write-back being enabled. Logged in as the test user I can request a password change without any issues (AND this new password starts to work for online logins), however this is never replicated in my local AD (old password works, new password doesn't).

There's an event log that happens at the same time the password is changed, but it doesn't really get me anywhere.

```
TrackingId: 5a76d0fc-3248-42b6-9a7a-cf8265766f38, HeartBeat for Namespace: ssprdedicatedsbprodscu, Endpoint: 3333b860-8fed-4146-aaeb-682401d60e10_2f466786-5627-462d-bcf7-ffc4bf83e8a0, Details: Version: 5.0.0.1541
```

I also tried to use the AD Connect troubleshooting portal, but that detected no faults.

Any idea how to proceed with debugging / fixing this?

Comment: Password writeback is a "premium" feature not available with Azure AD Free or Basic. Most Office 365 subscriptions are backed by Azure AD Basic. See these links for more info. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-writeback - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/

Comment: @joeqwerty We have an E3 licence, so that should cover write-back, no?

Comment: I don't believe so. An Office 365 E3 subscription doesn't include Azure AD Premium, AFAIK. A Microsoft 365 subscription does.

Comment: It can also be purchased separately, but sometimes EMS adds most value for a reasonable price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joeqwerty this is a premium feature available only to AzureAD P1 and P2 subscriptions.

[image]

This is the current page that covers licensing and the password management options with AzureAD:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-licensing

Comment: I'm a bit confused. According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-writeback) link the Office 365 E3 licence should be supported. We ARE using Office 365, and can assign those licences to our users... is there a difference between assigning an E3 licence to a user in O365 and the licencing available in Azure?

Comment: I'll accept this... I would prefer there to be a more clear-cut error telling me "sorry, but your licence is wrong for password write-back" or something, but when I accessed Azure it seems we don't have P1/P2... Anyway, MS seems to be harder to follow than Malbolge when it comes to licencing... :(

Comment: Office 365 E3, Microsoft 365 E3, and EMS E3 are all seperate products. The latter two have Azure AD P1 included the first one does not.  Of all the current SaaS offerings Azure AD is the most confusing in terms of what you get at each subscription level.